# TinyMCE Failed to initialize plugin: code error in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce

I've been trying to add TinyMCE editor to my WordPress plugin. I'm aware that we can use the `wp_editor()` function to achieve this but it doesn't work when I call it via ajax. I've tried a few solutions for it but then managed to make it work directly.

The issue I'm having now is that it's giving an error for the 'code' plugin.

Here is the code for tinymce:

```
tinymce.init({
        menubar: false,
        selector: '#p_' + r,
        plugins: 'code',
        skin_url: '../wp-includes/js/tinymce/skins/lightgray'
    });
```

I'm getting this error on the editor:

> `Failed to initialize plugin: code`

Console Errors:

[image]

PS: I've checked the plugins directory and the 'code' plugin folder is present i

Comment: Update: I tried adding other plugins but it seems like it's not accepting any plugin.

Comment: As per your error make sure you have given the right selector `selector: '#p_' + r,`.

Comment: Thank you @Bhautik but that is not the issue, The selector value is correct.